# php create beautiful query string from long query string

Tags: php, query-string

i want to create a beautiful query string from long and easily understandable query string

for example

```
http://www.domain.com/play.php?a=10&b=20&c=30
```

first of all this is vary long query string and second it is understand able that value of a,b&c.

what i want is  php function which convert whole query string to `a=10&b=20&c=30` to some text like `f4cdret4`

and then i pass same like

```
http://www.domain.com/play.php?q=f4cdret4
```

and in **play.php** i again convert back `f4cdret4` to `a=10&b=20&c=30`

i am trying to find some thing like that but many days searching no success.

Thanks

Comment: I guess http://www.domain.com/play.php?q=a10b20c30 is not an option :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a BAD idea from a usability perspective. I as a user would be annoyed with you. I recommend you read about [URL Design](http://warpspire.com/posts/url-design/).

Also, sounds like you want to keep something from the user. If so it's *not secure* if you do something like

```
$url .= '?q=' . base64_encode(http_build_query($parms));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use some string transformation functions to hide the real query string. Here is a simple example I came up with using `bin2hex` and `pack`

```
<?php
$str = 'a=10&b=5&c=20&d=6';
$encoded = bin2hex($str);
echo $encoded;
echo "\n";
echo pack("H*",$encoded);
?>
```

[example](http://codepad.org/JUC0CvaE)
You can use `bin2hex` to encode it, and `pack` to decode it.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, you don't want to divorce your URL from any semblance of meaning for the user unless you are significantly shortening it for use in character-limited settings like a Twitter post.

That said, there are a few ways to implement this. You can:

- Pre-generate these URLs and store the cross-referenced query string in the database (use "f4cdret4" as a unique index, "a=10&b=20&c=30" as a second column)
- Mash them together with some kind of separator (a=10&b=20&c=30 becomes "a10-b20-c30")
- Use htaccess to make pseudo-directories (a=10&b=20&c=30 becomes "mydomain.com/q/10/20/30")

  `RewriteEngine On`

  `RewriteRule /q/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ /page/play.php?a=$1&b=$2&c=$3`